# Get related column on .annotate() data Django

Tags: django, django-select-related, rawsql

I created this simple set of data to illustrate my point. It is a simple model with no further relations to any other model.

[image]

I need to group the data above by topicid, find the max date for each group and then get the author for that date.

```
info = TempModel.objects
       .values('topic')
       .annotate( max=Max('date'))
       .order_by('-max')
```

Iterating through this in a template,

```
  <table>
      {% for item in info %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.topicid }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.max }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.author }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

produces,

[image]

How do I display the 'author' column for each max date?

I can do this with a raw sql query like this,

```
info = list(TempModel.objects
       .raw('SELECT *, max(date) AS max 
       FROM crudapp_tempmodel 
       GROUP BY topicid 
       ORDER BY date DESC'))
```

But I want to do it using a Django query.

The output I am looking for is,

[image]

If this is not possible with a Django query I would like to know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to amalgamate another query which compares date from one query with max from the other.

Here is the view that does this,

```
def temp(request):
    info2 = TempModel.objects.all()
    info = TempModel.objects
           .values('topic')
           .annotate( max=Max('date'))
           .order_by('-max')

    columnlist = []
    for item in info2:
         columnlist.append([item])

    for item in info:
        for i in range(len(columnlist)):
            if item['max'] == columnlist[i][0].date:
                item['author'] = columnlist[i][0].author

    return render(request, 'template.html', {'info': info, 'info2': info2})
```